# Updating modal values on button click without reload

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently trying to learn node.js with express and bootstrap. I'm trying to update the values inside "pre" tags after clicking on generate button. I'm assuming that it can be done via AJAX but I'm having problem how to properly implement it.

Currently, the API_Key & API_Secret are being pulled from "req" content after logging in. User then have a navbar link to open modal to get API Keys or generate a new one.

[Modal][1]

Here are the codes that I have so far.

```
//Route js  
router.get('/api/generate', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    db.Account.findOne({ where: {email: req.user.email} })
    .then(Account => { 
        Account.update({
            API_Key: uuidv4(),
            API_Secret: uuidv4()
        });
        req.flash('success_msg', 'New API Keys successfully generated.');
    });
});

//.ejs modal
<div class="modal fade" id="APIModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <%= success_msg %>
                              <h5 class="modal-title">API Token</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <a>API Key</a>
                                <pre style="display: flex; word-break: break-word; white-space: normal; background: #eeeeee" id="preKey"><%= API_Key %></pre>
                                <a>API Secret</a>
                                <pre style="display: flex; word-break: break-word; white-space: normal; background: #eeeeee" id="preSecret"><%= API_Secret %></pre>
                                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-warning">
                                    <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
                                    <p class="mb-0">Generating a new token will invalidate previous tokens.</p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <a href="/api/generate" type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" id='generateAPI'>Generate</a>
                              <!--<button href='/generate' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Generate</button>-->
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk64g.png
```

Comment: have you tried AJAX?

Comment: I've have tried using jquery with AJAX nothing seems to happen when I try it. Probably was using it incorrectly. I'm new to all these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all good now. Figured out how to update it using AJAX.

Thanks!

```js
$("#generateAPI").on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var uid = $(".uid").val();
    var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to generate new set of keys?');
    if(!confirmation){
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/generate",
        method: "POST",
        data: {uid: uid},
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data){
        var key = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        changeKeysDisplay(key.API_Key, key.API_Secret);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    })
```